# How to store debug symbols and binaries side-by-side

Tags: dbghelp, symbol-server, symstore

Recently I noticed that when downloading symbols from Microsoft symbol store using SymChk it brings DLLs as well as PDBs.
I'm wondering if it is possible to store both binaries and symbols using standard microsoft tools like SymChk/SymStore?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was pretty obvious. Just do not mention the extension you want to add.
for example, instead of using:

add /r /f "\buildserver\buildresults*.pdb" /s "\fileserver\R&D\Artifacts\Symbols\" /c "Adding production symbols" /t "server symbols" /v "1.0.0.1"

use:

add /r /f "\buildserver\buildresults*.*" /s "\fileserver\R&D\Artifacts\Symbols\" /c "Adding production symbols" /t "server symbols" /v "1.0.0.1"